# How much registers per thread does OpenCL kernel use on Nvidia GPU?

Tags: opencl, gpu, nvidia

My First Question is How to get registers used information for OpenCL kernel code on Nvidia GPU, as nvcc complier gives the same using `nvcc --ptxas-options=-v` flag for CUDA kernel code.

I also got the same information on AMD GPU for OpenCL kernel, from `.isa file` generated while running the program, after exporting `GPU_DUMP_DEVICE_KERNEL=3`. Same thing i also tried on Nvidia GPU but it did not get `.isa file`. My second question is that why Nvidia GPU not generating `.isa file` ?

After googling I found the way to get registers and shared memory used information for OpenCL kernel on Nvidia GPU is to use `cl-nv-verbose` string flag  into the clBuildProgram() function call. And then read "binaries" information of complied kernel code.
    My third question Is it correct way to get registers used information on Nvidia GPU? What are the others way to get same ?

//Building the program...

```
clBuildProgram(program, 1, &device_id, "-cl-nv-verbose", NULL, NULL);
```

after building the program i used two constants `CL_PROGRAM_BINARY_SIZES and CL_PROGRAM_BINARIES` into the clGetProgramInfo() function to get binaries of compiled kernel code.

//  Printing Binaries of complied kernel code...

```
cl_uint program_num_devices, ret;
    size_t t;
    ret = clGetProgramInfo(program, CL_PROGRAM_NUM_DEVICES, sizeof(cl_uint), &program_num_devices, NULL);
    if(program_num_devices == 0) {
            printf("No valid device was found \n");
            return ;
    }
    size_t binary_sizes[program_num_devices];
    char **binaries = (char **) malloc(program_num_devices * sizeof(char* ));
    //first call to get size of ISA binary file...
    ret = clGetProgramInfo(program, CL_PROGRAM_BINARY_SIZES, program_num_devices * sizeof(size_t), &binary_sizes, NULL);
    for(t = 0; t < program_num_devices; t++) {
            binaries[t] = (char *) malloc((binary_sizes[t] + 1) * sizeof(char));
    }
    //second call to get ISA info....
    ret = clGetProgramInfo(program, CL_PROGRAM_BINARIES, program_num_devices * sizeof(size_t), binaries, NULL);
    for(t = 0; t < program_num_devices; t++) {
            binaries[t][binary_sizes[t]] = '\0';
            printf("Binary ISA Info%s : %lu \n", binaries[t], binary_sizes[t]);
    }
    printf("ProgramNumDevices:: %u\n", program_num_devices);
    for(t = 0; t < program_num_devices; t++) {
            free(binaries[t]);
    }
```

This is printing "binaries" of my complied OpenCl kernel code. But it is not displaying registers and shared memory used information. Why?

Please share some useful informations .

Thanks in Advance !!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a quick search, it looks like that after building the program with `-cl-nv-verbose`, you get the verbose output with `clGetProgramBuildInfo(...,CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG,...)`.

Comment: I have one more problem about global_work_size, as we know the only constraint for the global_work_size is that it must be a multiple of the local_work_size (for each dimension). So how to handle if global_work_size is not multiple of local_work_size ?

Comment: You should probably post another question about this.  You can have global work size a little larger, for example the next multiple of your best local work size, and then have each work item check if it is out of bounds, and return immediately if it is.