# Local memory and registers scale linearly with work group size - how to choose optimal size?

Tags: opencl

My kernel's local memory and register usage scale linearly with work group size. Besides trial and error, are there guidelines for choosing the optimal work group size? I am targeting AMD hardware, where the maximum work group size is 256; should I try to maximize the number of work items in group, or does this risk reducing occupancy and creating register spilling?

Comment: Are you sure it scales linearly? Ressources (local memory and registers) are shared among all work groups. Don't you mean it scales linearly with your total problem size ?

Comment: Yes, you are right. What I mean is: double the work group size requires double the local memory per work group, etc......

Comment: Lots of factors come into play; if you're going to run on fixed hardware do profiling to find the optimal work group size.

Answer (score 0):

You should do both : try to maximize occupancy avoiding register spilling at all costs i.e. get the most of the resources available on your platform.

If you are using nvcc, you can get the number of registers a single thread would need to execute your kernel [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10126020/how-much-registers-per-thread-does-opencl-kernel-use-on-nvidia-gpu). Then using this information with the local memory needed (that's your input) you can use [the CUDA occupancy calculator](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.download.nvidia.com%2Fcompute%2Fcuda%2FCUDA_Occupancy_calculator.xls&ei=4VpSVOHOM4qVavCOgrgF&usg=AFQjCNG_VhxwvgVBBUZnnincdbTyvYLrKQ&sig2=hO7PJCM42Bo22ZNkF6babA) to see the impact on occupancy. That does not replace a good old "trial-and-error" though.

EDIT: You are using AMD. I don't know how you can map NVIDIA compute capability to AMD devices though.